# Is there a way to sort strings inside an array, based on parts of the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to program a simple Italian dictionary. I want to be able to sort by parts of the string. I'm keeping the Italian, English, and information together. Here's a link to the full code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/dJe80d7m

I split them by the ":" character. That way, I can have "Ghiaccio" in the Italian area, "Ice" in the English area, and "(singular, m)" in the info area. When I try to sort using this method, the translations get mixed up.

```
word_bank = [
"Animale:Animal:(singular, m)",
"Animali:Animal:(plural, m)",
"Libro:Book:(singular, m)",
"Libri:Books:(plural, m)",
"Zucca:Pumpkin:(singular, f)",
"Zucce:Pumpkins:(plural, f)",
]
word_bank.sort()
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to be able to organize the Italian words alphabetically, and also organize the English words alphabetically. If I press "Organize by English, I want the English words to be ordered, and still paired up with the Italian translations. Same thing with the Italian (I press "Organize by Italian", the Italian words are organized, but still paired with the English words).

Comment: Don't do that. It is bad practice to combine different data items in a concatenated string. Use arrays or objects inside your array.

Comment: @trincot Agreed, the approach to sorting them is the same though as if they were serialised into a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround for your problem:

```js
const word_bank = [
    "kucce:Pumpkins:(plural, f)",
    "Zucca:Pumpkin:(singular, f)",
    "Animale:Animal:(singular, m)",
    "Libro:Book:(singular, m)",
    "Libri:Books:(plural, m)",
    "Animali:Animal:(plural, m)",
];

const sortByLanguage = (arr, sortBy) => {
    if(['italian', 'english'].indexOf(sortBy) === -1) {
        throw new Error("Invalid Enum Value For 'sortBy'.");
    } else {
        const index = (sortBy === 'italian') ? 0 : 1;
        const splittedArray = arr.map(a => a.split(':'));
        const sortedSplittedArray = sortSplittedArray(splittedArray, index);
        const sortedByLanguage = sortedSplittedArray.map(x => x.join(':'));
        return sortedByLanguage;
    }
}

const sortSplittedArray = (arrToSort, index) => {
    arrToSort.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[index].toLowerCase() < b[index].toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a[index].toLowerCase() > b[index].toLowerCase()) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
    return arrToSort;
}

const sortedByEnglish = sortByLanguage(word_bank, 'english');
const sortedByItalian = sortByLanguage(word_bank, 'italian');

console.log('Sorted By English Is: => ', sortedByEnglish);
console.log('Sorted By Italian Is: => ', sortedByItalian);
```

Note: you can remove **toLowerCase()** from **sortSplittedArray()** method if you want case sensitive sorting.

Hope this helps :)